# Can a Parallels VM be salvaged from a recovered .hds file (200gb file)?

Tags: parallels-desktop

The computer got hosed & we lost the `.pvm` file, then the Time Machine Backup drive was involved in a car crash!
I know the `.pvm` file is a package with multiple files inside, but I've looked thru the recovered data & can't find a `.pvm` file.

I see multiple `.hds` files, but no `.pvm` file.

I am using Parallels 7 & trying to re-create the `.pvm` file on an external drive but am not having much luck. Changed the name of the file to `**.hdd`, attached with Parallels, but the VM complains that the Hard Drive is not there.  Possibly I am not understanding the basic contents needed for a viable `.pvm` package?

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

The original problem with the Time Machine drive was "stiction", they put the drive into a  clean room to fix that, and as they were reading the data from the drive one of the heads failed.  Needless to say, the data recovery took 2 weeks, but I think we finally have all the data (in the form of raw files) from the Time Machine Backup drive now.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that just the partition table got trashed somehow, use [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to [re-write the partition table](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step):

> **TestDisk** is powerful free data recovery software! It was primarily designed to help recover lost partitions and/or make non-booting disks bootable again when these symptoms are caused by faulty software: certain types of viruses or human error (such as accidentally deleting a Partition Table). Partition table recovery using TestDisk is really easy.

Attach the virtual drive to another VM and use TestDisk from there.

This Parallel's support article describes the process, [Unmountable boot volume BSOD when you start Windows virtual machine](http://kb.parallels.com/en/114784).